# Python Selenium: Cannot locate pop-up menu

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to HTML and Selenium, and I have been struggling with trying to locate in the HTML script, the options within the pop-up menu seen in the image attached that is circled in red. One gets to the menu by either clicking or hovering the mouse over the small arrow button next to the pop-up menu:

[image]
[image]

The code below shows the steps I took to get to the pop-up menu, but I am unsure as to how to click on any one of the options in the pop-up itself (Note the pop-up menu doesn't open in a new browser, and disappears if one clicks outside of the menu):

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame('portfolio_canvas_area')
driver.switch_to.frame('canvas_area')
driver.switch_to.frame('canvas_task_frame')
driver.find_element_by_id('id.textentry.person.info').send_keys('Daniel Zhou')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('id.combobox.person.criteria'))
select.select_by_index(1)
driver.find_element_by_id('button.find').click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/span/div/div/form/span/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/span/span/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/div/span/span/span").click()
```

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Hey Arundeep, you were amazing at spotting details I missed before-Do you see something obvious that I'm not seeing? Sorry to drag you into this!

Comment: Do this manually. In your developer tools while clicking the element does the html change in anyway.

Comment: //a[@title='View popup menu'] is an easier xpath to use as well.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Hey Arundeep! Thanks so much for getting back to me, and I appreciate the tip for the xpath, I didn't know you could do that so I had to use an absolute path; but this simplifies it down so much more! Thanks!

Comment: @ArundeepChohan So I clicked on the element, but nothing is coming up in the HTML. Once I click on the element, it just takes me to a new tab instead of highlighting anything in the HTML script. I was however able to find a workaround, and was able to locate the element by linked text. I guess this would work also, but it's strange why I wasn't able to locate it manually this whole time though...

Comment: I tend to use a webdriver wait in combination with "[.='value']" sometimes with these.